# Excel Index match with multiple criteria using dates and numbers

Tags: excel

Given the following spreadsheet I would like to find the first date after 5/16/2015 that also has a Payment amount > 0. So a Next Payment Date of "7/1/2015" is what I'm looking for.

[image]

I tried the following formula: =INDEX(A4:A10,MATCH($E$1,$A$4:$A$10,1)+ 1) but that gives me 6/1/2015 since it doesn't check if the payment is > 0. I have tried various ways of adding the second criteria but haven't been able to get it to work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another Formula,  In E2:

```
=SMALL(IF(A4:A9>$E$1,IF(B4:B9>0,A4:A9)),1)
```

It is an array formula and must be confirmed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

This will find the first date after the date in E1 that is not 0 regardless of sort order.

Answer (score 1):

In E3 (.. F2?) as,

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A4:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,A:A )))/((A4:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,A:A ))>E2)*(B4:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,A:A ))>0)), 1))
```

You will have to format as a date. The initial result will be 42186.

Answer (score 1):

Use this array formula.

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

```
=INDEX(A4:A10,SMALL(IF(A4:A9>E1,IF(B4:B9>0,ROW(A4:A9)-ROW($A$3))),ROWS($A$4:$A4)))
```

[image]

Comment: `B2` cell have to date format, otherwise you will get a number.